# Slicing Pandas Dataframe according to number of lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I suppose this is something rather simple, but I can't find how to make this. I've been searching tutorials and stackoverflow.

Suppose I have a dataframe df loking like this :

```
Group   Id_In_Group   SomeQuantity
1        1              10
1        2              20
2        1               7
3        1              16
3        2              22
3        3               5
3        4              12
3        5              28
4        1               1
4        2              18
4        3              14
4        4               7
5        1              36
```

I would like to select only the lines having at least 4 objects in the group (so there are at least 4 rows having the same "group" number) and for which SomeQuantity for the 4th object, when sorted in the group by ascending SomeQuantity, is greater than 20 (for example).

In the given Dataframe, for example, it would only return the 3rd group, since it has 4 (>=4) members and its 4th SomeQuantity (after sorting) is 22 (>=20), so it should construct the dataframe :

```
Group   Id_In_Group   SomeQuantity
3        1              16
3        2              22
3        3               5
3        4              12
3        5              28
```

(being or not sorted by SomeQuantity, whatever).

Could somebody be kind enough to help me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach using `map`, `value_counts`, `groupby` , `filter`:

```
(df[df.Group.map(df.Group.value_counts().ge(4))]
   .groupby('Group')
   .filter(lambda x: np.any(x['SomeQuantity'].sort_values().iloc[3] >= 20)))
```

[image]

---

***Breakdown of steps:***

Perform `value_counts` to compute the total counts of distinct elements present in *Group* column.

```
>>> df.Group.value_counts()

3    5
4    4
1    2
5    1
2    1
Name: Group, dtype: int64
```

Use `map` which functions like a dictionary (wherein the index becomes the keys and the series elements become the values) to map these results back to the original `DF`

```
>>> df.Group.map(df.Group.value_counts())

0     2
1     2
2     1
3     5
4     5
5     5
6     5
7     5
8     4
9     4
10    4
11    4
12    1
Name: Group, dtype: int64
```

Then, we check for the elements having a value of 4 or more which is our threshold limit and take only those subset from the entire `DF`.

```
>>> df[df.Group.map(df.Group.value_counts().ge(4))]   

    Group  Id_In_Group  SomeQuantity
3       3            1            16
4       3            2            22
5       3            3             5
6       3            4            12
7       3            5            28
8       4            1             1
9       4            2            28
10      4            3            14
11      4            4             7
```

Inorder to use `groupby.filter` operation on this, we must make sure that we return a single boolean value corresponding to each grouped key when we perform the sorting process and compare the fourth element to the threshold which is 20.
`np.any` returns all such possiblities matching our filter.

```
>>> df[df.Group.map(df.Group.value_counts().ge(4))]         \
      .groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x['SomeQuantity'].sort_values().iloc[3])

 Group
3    22
4    18
dtype: int64
```

From these, we compare the fourth element `.iloc[3]` as it is 0-based indexed and return all such favourable matches.

Comment: Yes, this one works perfectly!!!! Thank you very much. I'm not sure to fully understand the answer, I should have a look to map for example, but I can use the result anyway! :) :) :) :)

Comment: Great answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I would use `.groupby()` +  `.filter()` methods:

```
In [66]: df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4 and x['SomeQuantity'].max() >= 20)
Out[66]:
   Group  Id_In_Group  SomeQuantity
3      3            1            16
4      3            2            22
5      3            3             5
6      3            4            12
7      3            5            28
```

Comment: would be better to not encourage accessing columns as an attribute even though this works in this case, e.g.: `df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4 and x['SomeQuantity'].max() >= 20)` +1 still

Comment: and should be & or no?

Comment: @TedPetrou here the lambda will be a single row value not an array so `and` is correct here

Comment: That's really perfect! Thank you very much @MaxU .

Comment: Thank you also  @EdChum for precision. :)

Comment: @EdChum Yes, filter passes the entire dataframe to the calling function so here its just evaluating two integers

Comment: @MaxU Oh, just a thing: the goal was not that x['SomeQuantity'].max() >= 20 , but that the 4th element of the sort of x['SomeQuantity'] be >=20... How do you sort that in lambda?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have worked through your question, warts and all.  Im sure there are much nicer ways to do this.

Find groups with "4 objects in the group"

```
import collections

groups = list({k for k, v in collections.Counter(df.Group).items() if v > 3} );groups

Out:[3, 4]
```

Use these groups to filter to a new df containing these groups:

```
df2 = df[df.Group.isin(groups)]
```

"4th SomeQuantity (after sorting) is 22 (>=20)"

```
 df3 = df2.sort_values(by='SomeQuantity',ascending=False)
```

(Updated as per comment below...)

```
df3.groupby('Group').filter(lambda grp: any(grp.sort_values('SomeQuantity').iloc[3] >= 20)).sort_index()

    Group   Id_In_Group SomeQuantity
  3    3        1       16
  4    3        2       22
  5    3        3       5
  6    3        4       12
  7    3        5       28
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really need to sort this out. :) Unfortunately, it seems that your method doesn't work either : if I set SomeQuantity to be 19 instead of 22 in group 3, it still returns group 3, although no group at all fits the criteria...